# CSS Display property cancelling Text-Align

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with alignments here.  I have jQuery populating a field for me.  I want to add the degree symbol which I did with an HTML Entity.  For some reason, when I give both items the display:inline property the text-align:center; property is ignored.  Can anyone explain why and how to fix?  Here is the code in question...

HTML

```
<h1 class="curr-temp" id="farh"></h1><h1 class="curr-temp">&deg</h1>
<button id="switch">F/C</button>
```

CSS

```
.curr-temp {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;  
}
```

Comment: Because when you set `display:inline`, the width of `.curr-temp` is *only as wide as the contents within it*, so alignment becomes mostly irrelevant.  Why are you setting it to `inline`? Where do you WANT it show up?

Comment: Try to use `display: inline-block` instead

Comment: @cyrix - that won't solve anything, inline-block will only be as wide as the contents within it also.

Comment: I don't see how the jQuery applies at all to your question

Comment: Yep right,  sry forgot he's not setting any witdh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you set `display:inline`, the width of `.curr-temp` is *only as wide as the contents within it*, so alignment becomes mostly irrelevant. And because you have both of those elements set to be `h1`, you are replacing the standard `h1` default of `display: block;`.

If you want them centered and inside of an `h1`, modify the markup like so:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="curr-temp" id="farh">5</span><span class="curr-temp">&deg</span></h1>
    <button id="switch">F/C</button>
```

This wraps both elements inside your desired `h1`, which will preserve the `text-align: center;`, but still gives you the markup `id` and `class` required to make your changes via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap both of two H1 tag inside of  tags.

When you set "inline" property for h1 or other head tags, then they will not have 100% width of wrapper. Couse of this will not be centered.